# Doctrine quoting apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I am using Doctrine ORM for php and Zend MVC. I have a mysql database. When I insert into the database it is escaping quotes. In other-words when I enter

```
<input name="customer_name" value="Test'ed user"> ...
```

into my form, and assign to a doctrine object and save.

When I look at the database through the mysql command line I get

```
Test\'ed user
```

Is there a way to disable this or do I have to call `stripslashes()` on each variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `magic_quotes_gpc` being enabled, either by looking at php.ini or running `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`.

If you have access to php.ini, then turn it off. Otherwise you'll need to remove the slashes in your scripts using `stripslashes()`.

Comment: So simple. Haven't used a server with that enabled in so long I forgot about that one! THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `magic_quotes_gpc` plague altogether by adding something like this to the top of your pages:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    if(!function_exists('stripishlashes_all')) {
        function stripslashes_all(&$data) {
            foreach($data as &$_value) {
                if(is_array($_value)) {
                    stripslashes_all($_value);
                }
                else {
                    $_value = stripslashes($_value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stripslashes_all($_REQUEST);
}
```

Very useful when your code is running on a server you don't have complete control over, or if you plan to distribute it.